# Problem with gmapping

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to build map using [gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM)  and i have already built that map but it seems to be inaccurate because the irobot   in map moves to forward and backward only ,but actually irobot has moved to right and left also and it dosen't appear in map

Can anyone tell me how to draw an accurate map?

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56135/problem-with-gmapping/) by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-02-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-02-25**:
Can you be more specific about what hardware you have, and how it's set up?

**Comment by [marwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3744/marwa/) on 2013-02-25**:
i am using  irobot create with kinect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check this: http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide Especially 2.2 and report results.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To improve your result's accuracy change the following parameters in gmapping launch file

1.Increase your laser range i.e. the parameter value "maxURange"
2.Increase your particle throttling frequency i.e. parameter value of "particles" from default 80 to around 120.
3.Reduce the parameter values of "linearUpdate" and "angularUpdate".

---

Originally posted by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) with karma: 311 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-11-11**:
hi Sudhanshu, can you please tell me what's the unit of   "maxURange", "linearUpdate" and "angularUpdate". Can you explan briefly what will happen if i put 100 as "linearUpdate". thanks

**Comment by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) on 2013-11-12**:
http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping